# How to disable forced soft wraps?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I open files with very long lines, IntelliJ forcibly wraps the lines and gives this message `this document contains very long lines. soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance`.

Following the instructions from this link, I disabled soft wrapping in general editor settings, and used the help menu to create an idea.properties file, in which I added `'editor.soft.wrap.force.limit=nnnnn`.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206704105-Forced-Soft-Wrap-in-Active-Editor-Window

However, intellij continues to wrap these lines unless I specifically disable them in the active editor. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should specify some large number instead of `nnnnn`, like

```
editor.soft.wrap.force.limit=100000
```

Notice that editor may become very slow. Default limit is 10000.

Comment: where is this idea.properties file in android studio 3.1, i cant find it

Comment: @Vaishakh Help | Edit custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

This bug appeared to me when I after doing a flutter pub get, due to an image in pubspec.yaml. After putting the image in my file, it showed this error, so link to that fact. The name of my image was brasao-governo-pmrr.png and it was inside the directory "assets/images/...". To solve this problem I just removed the file and removed it from pubspec.yaml. And go there!